# MediaWiki with short URLs and SSL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, mediawiki

I'm trying to set up a mediawiki site with short URLs and SSL enabled. I've been trying for some time now and this is my setup:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The code enables SSL, however the problem is that every insecure link is redirected to main page, rather than its https counterpart.

E.g going to:
wiki.com/article redirects to https://wiki.com/main_page rather than https://wiki.com/article

I can not configure apache, so htaccess is my only solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You can also edit LocalSettings.php file and change $wgServer value from http:// to https://. It will make all urls in the wiki secure by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution is rather simple - I had to display the https rules first.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```